# Page breaks after reload VueJS + Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have strange problem. I'm creating my application where I have a couple of pages. Normally it looks ok:
[image]

But this is what happens when I reload the page:

[image]

As you can see, I pressed Ctrl + A just to show you that there is a text. Second reload doesn't help. My application is made on `VueJS` + `NuxtJS`. Did anyone meet that?

Here is HTML, if it can be useful:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <SideBar :subpages='subpages' @clicked="filterByDate" />
    <div class='blog-header'>
      <div class='search-div'>
        <input class='search-field' placeholder='Search...'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='post-content'>
      <div v-if='$route.params.id'>
        <h1 class='big-text post-title'>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <h1 class='big-text post-title'>{{ post }}</h1>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <div v-for='title in categoriesAndPretitles' :key='title.section'>
          <div v-if='$route.params.category === title.section'>
            <h1 class='big-text post-title'>{{title.title}}</h1>
            <p class='description-text'>{{title.text}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-for='p of posts' :key='p.id'>
          <div class='post-preview' @click='toPost(p.id, p.type)'>
            <div class='post-preview-img'></div>
            <div class='post-preview-content'>
              <p>{{ p.title }}</p>
              <p class='plot'>{{ p.plot }}</p>
              <p class='date'>{{ p.created_at }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--    <Footer />-->
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Not sure how you can expect us to help you with just images.

Comment: What do you want to see? Just peaces of HTML? I don't think it will be useful

Comment: Try to find something useful to show us. Try to be on our side, would this be enough to fix somebody's problem, by just looking at images? A [repro] or some settings/markup mainly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, answer is kinda silly, because it was about styles. I mean, styles wasn't import correctly. For main page I have this style:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #181919;
}
```

And for some reason this style also worked, for which I didn't import file with this style. And after reload it crused, but now, just by importing it work fine :p